# create-react-app is showing all my code in production, how to hide it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

[image: showing_all_files]

In my chrome sources tab, I am able to view all my files by exact folder location. How can I hide them?

These weren't the problem in my previous project, which were made without using create-react-app.

Comment: you can't do anything. it's a feature

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It seems to be correct behaviour in create-react-app according to [Issue #1632](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1632).

[Gaeron](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1632#issuecomment-282287745):

> This is expected. You can delete .map files from the build output if
> you want to disable it, although you'll get console warnings about
> them missing.
>
> There is no harm in leaving them in though in my opinion. Client code
> is already available to the user’s machine so there’s no secrets in
> it.

Also ensure you have proper production build, the output of `npm run build`/`yarn build` is the one which should be deployed to your server.

If you want to completely disable generation of source maps use:

```
scripts: {
  "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
}
```

You can also specify `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` parameter via `.env` configuration files or use in plain console command `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build`.

Comment: only removing *.map files didn't do it. But, commenting out the service worker too did the trick.

Comment: @SabbiuShah Service Workers are vital part of React app as they stand for caching, optimising, fast-loading and offline working. Please keep in mind that not using them is a huge drawback.

Comment: But, I don't want to show exact code. In your suggestion, what can be done?

Comment: @SabbiuShah JS code is always available, generally on production build should be available only minified one. Still though, there is no guarantee someone would not steal your code (as this is specific case for client-side). If you feel that you need additional protection you might consider using code obfuscation, eg with [webpack-obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator).

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I just want the code to be minified in client side, so that it gives hard time for anyone trying to steal the code. But, in this case, exact folders with file structure, everything are shown. javascript is accessed from  bundle####.js, which is minified (by default by create-react-app), then, why and how is it showing all the exact files and folder

Comment: @SabbiuShah I could only guess as I cannot see your server, but it is possible the *.map's get somehow cached and that's why after deleting them you still see the code on production, but it's nothing certain.

Comment: Yeah! you're right. While accessing site in private mode, the content weren't showing now... Thanks :)

Comment: What is the point of `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP`? Why is it default to True?

Comment: the [build command for windows users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61967190/6908282) should be this: `"build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build"`

Comment: I have added it to the build command, but it still shows the code. Do you have a clue?

Answer (score 38):

Make this change in `package.json` file and you are good to go.

```
scripts: {
  "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can say that this works on my MacOS.

Answer (score 30):

### Here are three ways to hide code.

**1. Using  `.env`  File.**

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

[image]

**2. Using `command` line.**

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build
```

**3. Using `package.json`**

```
scripts: {
  "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP`? Why is it default to True?

Comment: All of these ways are really the same but different ways to set the `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP` environment variable to false.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build` on linux/mac

Comment: This was pretty helpful!

Comment: What is the point of `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP`? Why is it default to True?

Comment: I asked this to @dan_abramov a while ago but couldn't get an answer.

Comment: @user14358266 As I know, source map is the one which is in the attached screenshot in the question. Sourcemap will automatically gets generated to when you build the project. Source map could be useful to debug your code after the project gets deployed. If you don't want it to get generated you should do what's in the accepted answer.
Refer this article to get a better understanding -> https://dev.to/myogeshchavan97/how-to-hide-your-react-source-code-from-getting-displayed-in-chrome-dev-tools-when-deployed-to-production-41j7

Answer (score 4):

In in **package.json** (Windows)

```
"scripts": {
...
    "cleanBuild": "rimraf ./build/*",
    "build": "npm run cleanBuild && set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build ",
...
}
```

Comment: What does the build: do can you please provide an explanation

Answer (score 3):

Among below three methods, I prefer the last one because I don't want to worry about OS.

1 - Delete the map files and then deploy the build folder(not a professional way).

2 - Change the build command in the `package.json` as:

```
// For the Windows OS
"build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build"

// For Linux OS
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
```

3 - Create or update `.env` file by adding

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the .map files (from js/ and css/ folder) before uploading to the production server

Answer (score 1):

On a windows machine, this helped me

```
"build": "set 'GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false' && react-scripts build",
```

Incase you are using `react-app-rewired` you can try the below.

I have used a package called as `cross-env`. It can inject your environment variables.

```
"build": "cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-app-rewired build"
```

Answer (score 1):

in package.json put the following code

---

```
scripts: {"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"}
```

[More information follow this blog](https://engineerscode.com/2021/03/21/how-to-hide-source-code-from-browser-console-in-create-react-app/)

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple solution that is:

```
npm run build nosources-source-map
```

For more information about differents ways: this is the [link](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)

Answer (score 1):

you cant remove access to your code.
You can use https://obfuscator.io to give headhash to hacker or code leecher.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, using package.json:

`scripts: { "build": "set 'GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false' react-scripts build" }`

Answer (score 0):

**For those who tried to add the variable and it still generates the map files:**

It's important to be aware that

> ```
> the build command for windows users should be this:
> ```

```
 "build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build"
```

As said @Gangula at the comments.

If not - it can cause the the map files will be generated.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73802887/generate-sourcemap-false-but-source-code-is-still-generated)

Answer (score 0):

Just update your **.env** file with `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you are facing is happening when deploying a CRA - Create React App application on Vercel, try configuring your package.json with the following property:

```
"postbuild":"rimraf build/static/**/*.map"
```

After searching a lot this was the only way that actually worked for me. The options suggested here were not sufficient for my case.