# GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false Issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, webpack, build

In windows when I tried to build react app I am getting error saying 'GENERATE_SOURCEMAP' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I have added below line in my package.json file

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
```

Comment: There's also this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Keep this in package.json:

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
"winBuild": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build",
```

Use `npm run build` for creating build on Linux.

Use `npm run winBuild` for creating build on Windows.

Comment: the answer is fine but there is a better solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62990101/1909798

Comment: @robsonrosa's comment: 
"build": "cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"

need to install cross-env before using this method.  

npm install --global cross-env

Comment: Do note that in linux you don't need the `&&` part, because in linux it's *a single* command.

Answer (score 24):

Another solution is to create a new file in your project's root directory named .env and include the following inside the file. This will remove any .map files from your build/static/js folder the next time you run build.

```js
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Answer (score 23):

Use `cross-env` to safely set environment variables across multiple operating systems:

`"build": "cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"`

Comment: Nice solution. FYI, need to install cross-env before using this method.  [npm install --global cross-env]

Comment: I tested this on Windows and mac successfully.

Comment: This should be the solution, and you can install cross-env as a devDependency for this to work (npm i -D cross-env)

Answer (score 16):

Also you can try the below setting in your scripts if you are running on windows

`"build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build"`

Comment: This has solved the problem. Sometimes at windows, "winBuild" doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

For windows

1. use **"set"** and
2. use **"&&"** in between,

like

```
"build": "set GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false && react-scripts build"
```

,this command also can be used to remove .map files after generated

```
"build": "react-scripts build && del build/static/js/*.map"
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this would help you, create new app:

```
npx create-react-app app

cd app
```

and then run:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false yarn build
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Cross Platform**: Just open `.env` and add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`

**Linux**:   `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`

**Windows**:
`set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\"`

Answer (score 0):

create a file name `.env`

add this code to the file : `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`

On Heroku, go to Settings -> Config vars -> add GENERATE_SOURCEMAP with value false

On Vercel, go to Settings -> Environment Variables -> add GENERATE_SOURCEMAP as key and False as value, set environment Production -> Save

Answer (score 0):

> Source Maps are enabled by default during development. During
> production builds, they are disabled to prevent you leaking your
> source on the client, unless you specifically opt-in with the
> configuration flag. When the productionBrowserSourceMaps option is enabled, the source maps will be output in the same directory as the JavaScript files. Next.js will automatically serve these files when requested.
> ~nextjs team

[NextJs Production Browser SourceMaps](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/productionBrowserSourceMaps)

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Heroku, you have to add this in the Config Vars inside the settings of your App. This is the way is supposed to be set from the documentation [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/)