# want to disable the source after deployment

Tags: reactjs, webpack

"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false npm run build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},

getting error 'GENERATE_SOURCEMAP' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61967190/1688785

Answer (score 0):

`GENERATE_SOURCEMAP` is an environment variable, setting them varies based on your operating systems.
check how to set environment variables for your OS.