# why i am seeing original code files and directory structure in sources panel in chrome?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, netlify

I deploy my production build folder in netlify with below structure:

[image]

but in chrome under sources panel i can see original project directories and code. Why is that? how can I prevent this? I am using webpack. App was created via create-react-app.

[image]

Comment: Is this using `npm start`?

Comment: no. i build it in prod mode. npm run build

Comment: You should add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build` to your build script, or try other solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415780/create-react-app-is-showing-all-my-code-in-production-how-to-hide-it)

Comment: yes sort of. It let me find the root cause. I had to find how to disable source map in another query. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution worked for me is to add below env variable in .env file in root dir. This will remove any .map files from your build/static/js folder the next time you run build.

GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false