# How can I completely hide code from people inspecting my React app with developer tools (including the 'Application' tab)?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

This question is not a duplicate of [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415780/create-react-app-is-showing-all-my-code-in-production-how-to-hide-it) as it refers to the `Application` tab of the developer tools. I followed what was advised on the other question and the code from the `Sources` tab went away.

However, the production build code will still show up under the `Application` tab, especifically beneath `Frames`, `top` and `Scripts`. It is all in a single file named something like `main.5b8eb24hkhr2.chunk.js`.

Is there a way to hide it?

ps: my project has a Firebase backend.

Comment: No, you can't hide it.

Comment: Do Facebook, Twitter and Reddit (all React apps) allow anyone to see their code by just going to the ```Application``` tab?

Comment: All sites allow it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't, You don't have control over that. As far as the files are included as scripts there are going to be available consider using `obfuscation`

Comment: is this the technique big companies with React front ends (Facebook, Twitter) use?