# Google app-engine deploy all my react file even sources

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine to host and serve my website, but I am encountering one issue when browsing on my website, I can retrieve all the source code I wrote in the dev tools:
[image: Files retrieved]

Here are the two commands I am using when building and deploying :

```sh
"build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
"deploy:client-production": "copy app_to_add_in_build.yaml build/app_to_add_in_build.yaml && cd build/ && move app_to_add_in_build.yaml app.yaml && gcloud app deploy --project myProjectId",
```

I am copying & renaming my `app.yaml` to the build folder then running the deploy from there.

Here is the content of my `app.yaml` file:

```yaml
runtime: nodejs12

handlers:
  - url: '/service-worker.js'
    secure: always
    static_files: service-worker.js
    upload: service-worker.js
    mime_type: application/javascript

  - url: /(precache-manifest.*)$
    secure: always
    mime_type: application/javascript
    static_files: \1
    upload: ./(precache-manifest.*)$

  - url: /(.*\.js)$
    secure: always
    static_files: \1
    upload: .*\.js$
    mime_type: application/javascript

  - url: /(.*\.(css|map|png|jpg|svg|ico|json|txt|woff))$
    secure: always
    static_files: \1
    upload: .*\.(css|map|png|jpg|svg|ico|json|txt|woff)$

  - url: '/(.*)'
    secure: always
    static_files: index.html
    upload: index.html
```

Plus here is the content of the build folder

[image: content of build folder]

As we can see, there are no source files inside.

Once this is deployed, I browse the files in Google cloud debugger:

[image: Google cloud debugger files]

There are no source files inside.

I cleared my cache and cookies, reset my browser data, and tried with several browsers, I still have access to all Javascript/JSX sources. When serving the website, I see that it is using a React production build, but I am sure it's using the javascript files inside instead, as components are mounted twice (https://medium.com/@andreasheissenberger/react-components-render-twice-any-way-to-fix-this-91cf23961625).

I don't know where the issue comes from as nothing is cached anymore, neither on GCP, neither on my computer...

Do you have any clues if I did something wrong? Or any fixes?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

After searching around and how the source code could be available, I try to serve it to myself and the code was still present.

After some other research I found that it's an intended feature or react scripts:
[create-react-app is showing all my code in production, how to hide it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415780/create-react-app-is-showing-all-my-code-in-production-how-to-hide-it)

Answer (score 0):

Is there ever going to be a situation where you want these sources files to be deployed / available on the remote server? You could just opt to not even deploy them, by adding them to your `.gcloudignore`. In the example below, all files ending in jsx would not get uploaded

```
*jsx
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore