# How to hide `/var/app/current` source code in elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, create-react-app

I am trying to deploy a basic react application in elastic beanstalk and when I inspect the browser I can see the source code:

[image: app source code]

The content of the react app is the default one from create-react-app with default package.json scripts.

The platform on elastic beanstalk is that one `Node.js 16 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.6.3`.

Despite I tried to add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` in npm build script, and try to configure nginx using proxy.conf, I'm unable to hide the `var/app/current` folder that is being deployed and has the source code of my react application.

Does someone know how avoid source code to be exposed on elastic beanstalk when deploying it in Node.js platform?

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415780/create-react-app-is-showing-all-my-code-in-production-how-to-hide-it

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag Indeed, I have tried it and it's not woking. As you can see my code it is not inside the static folder, is in a folder that maybe elastic beanstalk is using to save it